# ODBC + remote MySQL over SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, odbc

So the struggle is to connect to the remote database with ODBC.
I followed the guides which I found on the Internet. They told me to make a SSH tunnel because my host doesn't allow direct connections and I made one using PLink (Putty console).
I can even login into the database using the console (I have a screenshot but I can't post it due to reputation restrictions).

But when I try to setup MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration in the ODBC driver, i get

```
[08S01]  [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 
'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

My settings:

```
TCP/IP Server: localhost [I tried 127.0.0.1 with no result]
Port: 3307
User/Password: I use those which were successful in signing in through console 
Database: The list is empty so I cannot choose anything
```

plink is launched with

```
Params := '-v -ssh -2 -P 22 -C -l ******** -pw ******* -L 3307:ssh.******.nichost.ru:22 ssh.******.nichost.ru';
```

So port should be fine.
Idk what to do, I googled east and west and found nothing which helped me :( Please help.

Comment: so you can SSH with Putty with a PKI key, and sitting on localhost can connect to mysql via command-line. And you are trying to use that same key to get back in via an SSH tunnel thru ODBC but that has not worked

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your port forwarding setup. You're using
`-L 3307:ssh.******.nichost.ru:22` which makes port 3307 at your end behave as if it were port 22 at the remote end; but port 22 typically belongs to an ssh server, not a database server.

If your MySQL server is listening on port 3307 at the remote end, you'd need `-L 3307:ssh.******.nichost.ru:3307` to connect to it via port 3307 at your end.