# Crystal Reports/MySQL connection over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, crystal-reports, remote-server

does anyone know if there is an option to connect Crystal reports to a MySQL database over ssh? It works for me with PgAdmin to a PostgreSQL database, so I think maybe there is some way to do it with Crystal Reports too. Thanks and regards

Comment: Crystal Reports doesn't need to be aware of the ssh port forwarding. Just setup the port forward in ssh from 3306 locally to the remote port/socket of the MySQL server, and then connect Crystal Reports to the localhost:3306 port as the database. If you're stuck, provide your local OS, and the remote operating system/distro and something more specific can be given as an answer. Probably belongs on serverfault.com/ as its not really a programming question.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417724/odbc-remote-mysql-over-ssh-tunnel